# SQL using column value to get column value from another table, then using THAT value to get count of columns from a third table with that value?

Tags: sql, select

I have three tables:

```
Carrier(CarrierID(PK), FirstName, LastName)
Customer(CustomerID(PK), FirstName, LastName, RouteID(FK))
Route(RouteID(PK), CarrierID(FK), RouteName)
```

Each Route only has one carrier.

I need to display the count of customers that each carrier is responsible for.

I know I need to use the CarrierID to get the RouteID, and then use the RouteID to count the rows of Customers with that RouteID.

Can someone explain to me how that SELECT statement would look?

Comment: Are you familiar with `JOIN`?  It is a pretty basic SQL concept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need  the distinct number of customer you can use count(distinct  ..) group by and join

```
select r.CarrierID, count(distinct CustomerID )
from Route r
inner join Customer c on c.RouteID = r.RouteID
group by r.CarrierID


select r.CarrierID, c2.Firstname, c2.Lastname, count(distinct CustomerID )
from Route r
inner join Customer c on c.RouteID = r.RouteID
inner join Carrier c2 on c2.CarrierID = r.CarrierID
group by r.CarrierID, c2.Firstname, c2.Lastname
```

Comment: What if I needed to display the `Carrier.FirstName` and `Carrier.LastName` in the same result?